# pick random item from a list with constantly reapeating items, but not repeat one twice immediately after

Tags: python, random

I try to constantly show one of 5 possible items randomly (for a 100 times or so), BUT the important thing is that the SAME item is not allowed to be shown immediately after each other. There needs to be (at least) always one other item in between.

Any idea?

Thank you soo much

Comment: pick random item, if same as last picked item, pick another random item. lather, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the sample code below.

```
 import random                                                                                                            
 import sys                                                                                                               

 def special_select(d, num_to_show=100):                                                                                    
   selected = None                                                                                                            
   for i in range(num_to_show):                                                                                           
     selected = random.choice(list(d.difference([selected])))                                                                     
     print selected
```

You may try the function like follows.

```
 >> d = set(range(5))
 >> special_select(d)
```

Comment: thank you all so much. I will try to implement it in my script. .fingers crossed... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Remember the previous item and keep picking a new choice until it differs:

```
import random

def pick_random(options):
    last = next = None
    while True:
       while next == last:
           next = random.choice(options)
       yield next
       last = next
```

Use this as a generator:

```
>>> options = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> picks = pick_random(options)
>>> for i in range(100):
...     print(next(picks))
... 
1
5
4
3
2
3
(...)
3
4
5
```

Using `itertools.islice()` makes it easier to pick just 100:

```
from itertools import islice

for pick in islice(pick_random(options), 100):
    print(pick)
```

Comment: this doesn't guarantee you don't repeat the last pick from a call with the first pick of the next call.

Comment: @PaulEvans: I discovered that, yes, so I changed tack.

Comment: Doesn't work because the last element in one `random.sample` can be the same as the first in the next.  Good try, though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Now that's much more complicated than the algorithm I proposed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Incorrect.  Didn't notice your change of method.  Now it implements the algorithm I proposed to the OP.  We should stop doing their homework, though.

Comment: @MarioRossi: I had already changed my answer before you posted yours, btw; at least before I *saw* you had posted.

Comment: It's kind of easier to use `groupby` here ;)

Comment: @JonClements: Perhaps, I find the explicit generator to be more readable, personally.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  For such a simple algorithm, I don't think we needed to copy each other to arrive to the same result.  I'm getting zero rep this time because I refused to do OP's homework and was comforting myself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, MarioRossi thank you and all the others so much. Its not homework, just got stuck. I will try to implement what you proposed.

Comment: @MarioRossi thank you and all the others so much. Its not homework, just got stuck. I will try to implement what you proposed. – Mona 8 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Plenty.

- Determine number of times to iterate.
- Start a random number generator.
- Set variable `previous` to `None` or similar.
- Start iteration.
- Generate next random number and compare it with `previous`. If it is the same, skip it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice
from random import choice

choices = range(5)
items = (k for k, g in groupby(iter(lambda: choice(choices), None)))
for item in islice(items, 100):
    print item
```

This lets `itertools.groupby` handle consecutive duplicate values and `islice` means you can just skim some off, so if you wanted 50 of them, just use:

```
random50 = list(islice(items, 50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient one in Python, but what is done here is: when append the next item, the next item is sampled from the pool excluding the previous item.

```
def rand_chain(n, chos_from):
    rd_ls=[]
    rd_ls.append(random.choice(chos_from))
    for i in range(n-1):
        rd_ls.append(random.choice([v for v in chos_from if v!=rd_ls[i]]))
    return rd_ls

>>> rand_chain(10, range(10))
[8, 2, 9, 2, 9, 5, 9, 8, 2, 4]
```

If you use `numpy`, replace `[v for v in chos_from if v!=rd_ls[i]]` with more efficient stuff.